# FBML App - Important Questions for October 1 changes

Tags: security, fbml

I have Some Questions for October 1 changes -

1. For old FBML based Facebook Canvas Apps, do we need to enable
   secure canvas url?
2. Will the old FBML apps stop working if https is not enabled on the server?
3. What code change do we make to convert he old fbml app code to new system?

Answer (score 0):

1. I do not think you need a Secure URL.  But test it by navigating Facebook with HTTPS (change your settings)  and visiting your app. If it will require a Secure canvas URL it will prompt you to temporarly navigate facebook without HTTPS.
2. Should still work (try #1)
3. Depends on the Facebook Functionality on your page.  One of the easiest ways is using the Facebook JS SDK. 
   Here is a full tutorial that should let you get the initial setup and functionality: 
   http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/

Comment: You can't use the JS SDK on an FBML app.

Answer (score 0):

FBML apps do not need secure canvas url. Here is the answer given by Douglas Purdy, the head of developer relations: http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/?view=permalink&id=251904368186418